# Why am I unable to console log listening on port 3005?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, api, express

I just developed a Node/Express API that should connect to PostgreSQL database and after I wrote this inside of `index.js`:

```
const app = require('./src/app');
const pool = require('./src/pool');

pool.connect({
  host: 'locahost',
  port: 5432,
  database: 'socialnetworking',
  user: '<my-username>',
  password: ''
}).then(() => {
  app().listen(3005, () => {
    console.log('Listening on port 3005');
  });
}).catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

My expectation is to see `Listening on port 3005` inside my terminal and I do not see that, I do not even see an error, it just seems to hang.

Inside my `pool.js` file:

```
const pg = require('pg');

class Pool {
  _pool = null;

  connect(options) {
    this._pool = new pg.Pool(options);
    return this._pool.query('SELECT 1 + 1');
  };
}

module.exports = new Pool();
```

Now that `return` is returning a Promise from that `connect()` function. That's what the `return` is doing, it's a Promise that is only going to resolve when the query resolves successfully, but if the issue is that it's not resolving correctly, why is no error thrown?

The `app.js` has:

```
const express = require('express');
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

module.exports = () => {
  const app = express();

  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(usersRouter);

  return app;
};
```

Comment: Please show us what `require('./src/app');` exports.  If you are naming things the usual way of naming things, then it would be `app.listen(...)`, not `app().listen(...)`.

Comment: If you put a `console.log("database connected")` as the first line of your `.then()` handler, do you see that?  Or does it not get there?  These are some elemental debugging steps you need to take to follow how far your code is or isn't getting.

Comment: @jfriend00, I tried it that way and it still seems to just hang and not return `Listening on port 3005`.

Comment: I can't help you if you're not going to answer my questions.  Does it get to that `console.log()` at all?  The question here is whether it's the DB not resolving it's promise or the server not starting.  Which is it?

Comment: It never gets to the `console.log()`.

Comment: @jfriend00, I did notice a `;` missing from `SELECT 1 + 1;`, but after I added it, still just hanging.

Comment: Why pg database module are you using from NPM?

Comment: @jfriend00, `"pg": "^8.4.2",`

Comment: I'm not looking for the version.  I'm looking for which NPM module (there are multiple modules that provide postgres interfaces).  Please provide a link to the actual NPM module page.

Comment: @jfriend00, https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg

Comment: I don't know.  I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @jfriend00, no worries, thank you for your time and help.

Comment: @jfriend00, by the way I threw a console log inside of `connect()` method for the `Pool` class and so I believe the query is definitely hanging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is insane, I literally just erased my `index.js` file and rewrote it again, same code as before:

```
const app = require('./src/app');
const pool = require('./src/pool');

pool.connect({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432,
  database: 'socialnetworking',
  user: '<my-username>',
  password: ''
}).then(() => {
  app().listen(3005, () => {
    console.log('Listening on port 3005');
  });
}).catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

and it works now. It still does not seem to be catching the error when I deliberately break it, instead it just hangs as before, but other than that, it's working, with the same exact code as before as far as I can tell.